# Why does Google Drive re-sync all my files when I rsync down updates?

Tags: mac, rsync, google-drive

I'm using Google Drive on my mac.  To get files from a linux server synced into my Google Drive I run:

```
cd ~/Google\ Drive/backups/
rsync -t -l -r host:directory/ host-directory/ --delete-after
```

This works fine, but Google Drive resyncs all my files each time I do this, which is very slow and eats a lot of battery.  How do I keep it from doing that?

With some poking, it looks like when I run rsync the `mtime` doesn't change but the `atime` and `ctime` do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-c` option to rsync then it will compute checksums and only transfer if the file has changed.  This will keep rsync from bumping `ctime`, which is apparently what Google Drive uses in figuring out what to update.

Separately, this sounds like a drive bug: why aren't they using `mtime`?  And why are they uploading if the hash hasn't changed?